# TensorFlow: Random Normal Value from Distribution with Parameters=Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, normal-distribution

I want to create an output where I take a random value from a normal distribution, but have the parameters of the normal distribution be based on a Tensor Variable.

For example:

```
new = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.random.normal([1], x, 1.0), new)    
new = tf.map_fn(lambda x: np.random.normal(0, x, 0.1)[0], new)
```

Where "new" is of type `tf.Variable` that is one dimensional. This throws an error saying:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I'm quite certain this is from putting in a tensor as a parameter to those two random.normal functions. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  I cannot reproduce the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

In `Tensorflow Version 2.x`, Replacing `x` with `np.abs(x)` in the line,

`new = tf.map_fn(lambda x: np.random.normal(0, x, 0.1)[0], new)` resolves the error.

The code, which runs successfully when a `Tensor` is passed as a parameter to two `random.normal` functions is shown below:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

new = tf.Variable([1.])

new = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.random.normal(shape = [1], mean = x, stddev = 1), new)
new = tf.map_fn(lambda x: np.random.normal(0, np.abs(x), 1)[0], new)

print(new)
```

Output is shown below:

```
tf.Tensor([0.00095569], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```